# Can you set a event in the calendat app and set a alert to go off a day before the event?

Tags: iphone

I would like to make a app that puts a event in the calendar app and sets a alert to go off a day before for the event? I saw some code in stackoverflow for setting events for the calendar, but could not find anything about setting the Alert for it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, it is all documented in [Calendar and Reminders Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765).

When you create an [`EKEvent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/EKEvent) you can add an [`EKAlarm`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKAlarmClassRef/EKAlarmClassReference/EKAlarmClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/EKAlarm) with the [`addAlarm:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKCalendarItem/addAlarm%3a)